# Trigger not functioning correctly in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up a trigger to get it so if a new entry is either null or set to '000-00-00 00:00:00', that it will set the current datetime (NOW()).

I can get the trigger to set the datetime if I don't check for null or other value, but if I do, it doesn't fire.

I have tried the following and they are not working:

```
delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER applicationsolution_OnInsert BEFORE UPDATE ON applicationsolution FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN SET NEW.created = NOW(); END IF; END;// delimiter ;


CREATE TRIGGER applicationsolution_OnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON applicationsolution FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.created = IFNULL(NEW.created, NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
DROP TABLE applicationsolution;
CREATE TABLE applicationsolution (myid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                  created DATETIME);
```

Sample table.

```
delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER applicationsolution_OnInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON applicationsolution 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.created IS NULL
    THEN SET NEW.created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
  END IF;
END //
delimiter ;
```

Trigger - which works - see below.

```
INSERT INTO applicationsolution (created) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO applicationsolution (created) VALUES (NULL);
```

Sample data insert - will produce two records.

```
SELECT * FROM applicationsolution;

myid,created
==== =======
1,"2016-06-24 21:50:40"
2,"2016-06-24 21:50:40"
```

So far, so good for `NULL`s. Now for the `UPDATE` trigger:

```
delimiter // 
CREATE TRIGGER applicationsolution_OnUpdate 
BEFORE UPDATE ON applicationsolution 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
    THEN SET NEW.created = current_timestamp(); 
  END IF; 
END//
delimiter ;
```

Now do an update.

```
UPDATE applicationsolution  SET created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
WHERE myid = 2;


SELECT * FROM applicationsolution;
```

And the results:

```
myid,created
1,"2016-06-24 21:50:40"
2,"2016-06-24 21:54:30"
```

Note the timestamp change in record 2 which shows that if you try to `INSERT` a `created` of '0000-00-00 00:00:00', you get a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Does this do what you want? I think there are two problems with your code. It's not formatted properly - this made it very difficult to follow the logic and difficult to see that the second trigger was incomplete. You also put the `INSERT` code in the `ON UPDATE` trigger and vice-versa.

Furthermore, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` seems to work better than `NOW()`.